# How can I know which object is clicked in C#?

Tags: c#, focus, mouseleave

[image: The pic below is the screenshot of my C# app]

To make sure that the user name input is valid, I added such callback method to do the verification:

```
Regex UserNameRE = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]\w*$");
//being called when input box is not focused any more
private void UserNameInput_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //pop up a warning when user name input is invalid
    if (!UserNameRE.IsMatch(UserNameInput.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid User Name!");
        this.UserNameInput.Text = "";
        this.UserNameInput.Focus();
    }
}
```

The method will be called when user finished their inputting(the method is bounded with the event-"leaving the input box"). It works when user left a invalid User_Name and begin to enter a password.

But it also works when user click another tab, e.g. the Register tab. I don't want this happen. Because the user obviously don't wanna login anymore if he clicks "Register" tab, and my C# app shouldnot pop up a warning box and force them inputting a valid user name again.

How can the C# tell the difference of such 2 situations? It should be easy if I know which object is being clicked.

Comment: Why don't you do your check when the user clicks on the submit button ? You won't have the problem anymore ...

Comment: Do one thing.. Instead of "Leaving" Event, try password "OnSetFocus()" or something similar.. so that your predefined condition can be satisfied. But in this you will face one more issue. "What if user directly goes to password field", Do one more thing, once username field gets some input, enable the password field, till thn disable the input.. Hope you get it..

Comment: Thank you, @LaGrandMere . Doing the check after submit button being clicked must be easier, but it only solve the problem I met currently, it does't answer the question I raised. Maybe one day, I still have to achieve such function in another scenario.

Comment: To@Hiren Pandya :Till now, only this way works as I want. But it still looks like a not perfect one. What if I have more fields to fill with? e.g. username, password, sex, incomes, nickname etc. In this case, I have to add check logic in password_enter, sex_enter, incomes_enter, nickname_enter event. Kind of duplicated works, aren't they?

Comment: When the Leave event is fired, which control has the Focus ? If it's not the TextBox, you could be able to determine which elemnt has it and use or not your action. Another way to do this would be to determine the X and Y of the Cursor on hte Leave Event and if it's on the tabs, do nothing, else do your popup.

Answer (score 2):

You will have `source` of event in object `sender` in `UserNameInput_Leave` event.

```
private void UserNameInput_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //sender is source of event here
}
```

Comment: Won't the source will always be his Textbox in both cases ?

Comment: @LaGrandMere tell the truth, this method can't help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option:

```
private void UserNameInput_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender.GetType() != typeof(TextBox))
        {
            return;
        }
        TextBox tBox = (TextBox)sender;
        //pop up a warning when user name input is invalid
        if (!UserNameRE.IsMatch(UserNameInput.Text) && tBox.Name == UserNameInput.Name)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid User Name!");
            this.UserNameInput.Text = "";
            this.UserNameInput.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, dear @jordanhill123 . the leave event's sender is always the text box-"UserNameInput" itself. That means, the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there's a right solution for this particular scenario here.

When you add a handler to validate your control on mouse leave, definitely it will be executed first regardless you clicked on another control within the tab or another tab itself.

This normal flow can't be ignored easily. It must be possible by hanlding the message loop yourself but the event based flow, first leave focus, and selected index change (selecting) event will be fired. I would suggest you not to disturb the flow as the validation is client side and pretty fast. Instead of messagebox, I would recommend you to use `ErrorProvider` and attach to the control whenever required. Also messagebox is quite disturbing and as per your code, you're forcefully making it focus to the textbox again.

How about the following code?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ErrorProvider errorProvider = new ErrorProvider();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Validating += new CancelEventHandler(textBox1_Validating);
    }

    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.CausesValidation = true;
    }

    void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex UserNameRE = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]\w*$");
        if (!UserNameRE.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
        {
            errorProvider.SetError(this.textBox1, "Invalid username");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome way of giving a warning to client. But I still have to find something else to take the place of "leave event".

Comment: If you can handle the windows messages using WinProc, then you would be able to implement your logic but you've to balance between the cost and value you gain out of it.